# how to set session in phpbb?

Tags: php, phpbb3

As I am new to PHPBB and i have struck with a session setting issue. Please provide me some tutorial links which would help me to learn and fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find the following link useful: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php